# Combine two git repositories into one with two branches

Tags: git, merge

After Google-ing the whole day, I will have to ask experts to help me.

I cloned some public SVN repo that I converted to git. This repo has just one master branch, and it starts from some specific version, say 1.0.

I also have a git repo that was created independently, and that starts with the same 1.0 version. I created this because I wanted to hack some public project. I just downloaded the source code, created empty git repo, added version 1.0 and proceeded to hack on it. This repo also has just master branch.

Now, I would lie to create a third git repo, where version 1.0 would be the starting point, and it would have two branches: 'svn' and 'mystuff'. I would like to keep history of both branches.

```
       1.0
      /   \
     /     \
br. svn    br. mystuff
     |       |
   v1.1      v1.1'
   v1.2      v1.2'
   v1.3      v1.3'
    .          .
    .          .
```

If I had this I could easily get new revisions from SVN repo using svn2git, and easily merge them with my local "mystuff" branch. I don't need to push to SVN repo, just fetch new revisions from it.

Can you help me make using git fun again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind-of-hacky way is using `git format-patch` to export all the commits of a repo to a directory, `git checkout` the other's repo `1.0` branch, create a new branch (`git checkout -b new-branch`), and then `git am` your previously generated patches.

So, let's call `public` your clone of the public SVN repo, and `local` the git repo you made by downloading the source and hacked onto.

```
cd local
mkdir ../patches

# -o tells the output directory for the patches
# the git log ... gives you the hash of the second commit of the repo (the first one
# changes are already present in your 'public' repo
git format-patch -o ../patches/ $(git log --pretty=format:%H | head -n-1 | tail -1)

cd ../public
git checkout -b mystuff 1.0
# Apply patches
git am ../patches/*
```

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a perfect solution for my problem, but I keep getting this error: **already exists in index
Patch failed at 0001 initial commit**

I get this for every file in project. Would it bee to much trouble to provide a working examples for **git format-patch** and **git am**?

Comment: @user1832156 I think you may have to ignore the first commit, since that commit is the same tree your `1.0` branch already has. I updated the answer, try doing that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I hope this will be useful to someone else. I was getting so many *patch does not apply* errors, I finally gave up. I even manually committed first commit from my local repo, and adjusted your example to start from second commit, and I was still getting *patch does not apply*. Since, this was taking too much time, I gave up. But generally, your answer was correct one.